# Getting filemaker error "specified field is not found" during enter find and set field

Tags: find, field, filemaker

I'm using the code to perform a find in filemaker and getting an error message that the specified field is not found. Does anyone see what I'm missing?

```
Enter Find Mode []

Set Field [Contact Data::car ; "--" ]

Set Error Capture [on]

Perform Find[]
```

Comment: The script looks right. When does the error appear and what is the exact wording of the error?

Comment: The error is 'The specified field can not be found' . I'm putting the code into the custom privileges and limited view of our customers database. The error appear when saving the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with find step as the error capture set on just before this script step, so it should not produce an error message.

I think there is a problem with the related field (Contact Data::car) and it is not directly related to the current layout relationship.

The simplest way to check it is to run the same query manually.

Comment: go to View /"Find Mode" menu, type your search criteria in the Contact Data::car field and press Enter

Comment: Yes this does work when searching for the type of car or county in the field

Comment: Do you run your script from the same layout?